# Export to PDF doesn't include technologies under experience

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, export

Under the experience heading you are able to list detailed information about all of your experience and also summarise it in 10 or fewer technology keywords.

Unfortunately the technology keywords are lost when exporting to PDF. Is there any particular reason why? I would've thought that a few simple keywords summarising the key technologies would make things easier for a potential employer to skim read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's building now.  I added the tags just under the title of the project.

Comment: Cool, can't wait to see it live!