# Add Technical Skills under each experience when printing or exporting to PDF

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, export

When I print or export to PDF I can see the technical skills that I have "liked", but I really need to have the tags that I put on each experience which list out my tech skills.

Having them show up when I print or export would really be useful.

I've seen this question already on meta ([Export to PDF doesn't include technologies under experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133171/export-to-pdf-doesnt-include-technologies-under-experience)) but it's marked as status-completed, and when I go to export or print they aren't showing up.

Is this is a bug or was the feature reverted or something?

Comment: This should be resolved now, let me know if it still not showing up for you.

Comment: Awesome, works great!